# Перегрузка - а есть ли такое в PHP?

Tags: php

В других языках видел нечто подобное

```
function help(array name) {
echo '1';
}

function help(string name) {
echo '2';
}

help(array('Васек', 'Петруха'));
//выведет 1
help('Клавчиха');
//выведет 2
```

т.е. от типа передаваемого функции зависит вызов той или иной функции

есть ли такое в php и как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> PHP не поддерживает перегрузку функции, также отсутствует возможность переопределить или удалить объявленную ранее функцию.

Источник [php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.user-defined.php)

Comment: Что ж как фаталистично-то. Можно ведь побороться и найти решение.

Comment: @istem, решение в ответе @zloctb,  но это не перегрузка.

Comment: Классическое решение - это передача массива ИмяПараметра=>Значение. Это вполне эффективно работает, но формально - это не перегрузка.

Answer (score 0):

А если использовать [func_get_args](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.func-get-args.php) и в зависивости от переданного аргумента привести его к нужному типу и возвратить нужный результат.

Answer (score 0):

а что если попробывать тупо так:

```
<?
function help ($arg) {
if (is_array($arg)) echo "1";
elseif (is_string($arg)) echo "2";
elseif (is_int($arg)) echo "3";
else echo "5";
}
```